# Проблема с пробуждением телефона

Tags: android-sdk, android, события, activity

Проблема такая. Есть сервис. Он по интервалу вызывает активити, а в `onResume` этой активити прописано "просыпание телефона", то есть включение экрана и разблокировка через флаги

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

И всё работает нормально, если активити не видна пользователю. Но если блокнуть экран при включенной активити, то метод `startActivity(intent)` ничего не даст, а значит экран не будет включен. 
Запуск отдельного потока не помог (почему кстати - не понятно). А как разблокировать экран из сервиса, ума не приложу. Хранить экземпляр активити что ли?

Comment: Попробовал действительно передавать сервису ссылку на активити - и всё равно, если приложение вверху (было видно перед блокировкой) он упрямо не хочет разблокировать экран!

Answer (score 1):

Хоть и давно написал, отвечу, вдруг кто-то столкнётся с такой же проблемой, найдёт этот вопрос в гугле и увидит что на него нет ответа.
Решилась проблема очень просто. Она возникла из-за того что сервис не хочет запускать тоже самое активити, если оно уже запущенно. Берём и запускаем другое активити, в методе onCreate которого прописываем запуск нужной нам активити и финиш(). Всё )